# Create new SQL table column by splitting content of existing column

Tags: python, python-3.x, database, sqlite, split

I have an sqlite table with a column of codes separated by '.' or '-' or both. For example:

| code |
| --- |
| 9897.1t |
| gb5ffh-hy |
| dhy4.dt4-kj |

How do I create a new column taking the first part of the code only? Preferably as part of an sql command that can handle nonetypes.

| code | new_code |
| --- | --- |
| 9897.1t | 9897 |
| gb5ffh-hy | gb5ffh |
| dhy4.dt4-kj | dhy4 |

I can get a column in python to insert using the following code:

```
def get_column(src, table, column):
    col = src.execute('SELECT %s FROM %s' % (column, table)).fetchall()
    col = ['None' if v is None else v for v in col] # replace nonetypes with string
    col = list(set(col))
    col = [x.split('-', 1)[0] for x in col]

return col
```

but is there a way to do it in sql directly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a generic solution with SQL code for any number of chars:

```
WITH cte(char) AS (VALUES ('.'), ('-')) -- you can add more chars in the list
SELECT code,
       SUBSTR(t.code, 1, COALESCE(MIN(INSTR(t.code, c.char)) - 1, LENGTH(t.code))) new_code
FROM tablename t LEFT JOIN cte c
ON INSTR(t.code, c.char)
GROUP BY t.code;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.39&fiddle=e510cefbb9b99ac500902ad5a8b10a24).

Comment: this is perfect and creates the table of old column: new column- is there a way to save the new column to the existing database table t?

Comment: @user20862 check this: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.39&fiddle=eb4ddd2ee3e9ec895a51aadaa4ecbb1a